# How to know HttpResponse content is string or stream

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HttpClient 4.3.3 API.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Some requests will sent response in response body. Some requests are used to download files from server, that means client may write this content to file.

How to differentiate the response of above two types of requests using HttpResponse.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I thought "**entity.isStreaming()**" works for my use case. But it is returning true for me in all requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in normal usage, the difference on streaming v non-stream is encapsulated in the "entityutils.entity.consume" that you see below.  Code is from "CloseableHttpClient" in a usage pattern from POST.

```
 CloseableHttpClient...

public <T> T execute(final HttpHost target, final HttpRequest request,
        final ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler, final HttpContext context)
        throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    Args.notNull(responseHandler, "Response handler");

    final HttpResponse response = execute(target, request, context);

    final T result;
    try {
        result = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
    } catch (final Exception t) {
        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try {
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (final Exception t2) {
            // Log this exception. The original exception is more
            // important and will be thrown to the caller.
            this.log.warn("Error consuming content after an exception.", t2);
        }
        if (t instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) t;
        }
        if (t instanceof IOException) {
            throw (IOException) t;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
    }

    // Handling the response was successful. Ensure that the content has
    // been fully consumed.
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Response entities are always streaming (unless using cache enabled `HttpClient`). Request entities can be either streaming (backed by a non-repeatable `InputStream`) or non-streaming (backed by a String, byte array, File or a similar memory or file system bound object)